# In Vim how I can set a local match only for a specific filetype?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vimrc, highlighting

In [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) I can set local configuration as:

```
 setlocal number
```

How I can set a local match only for a specific filetype?

I use this:

```
 autocmd! BufEnter *.py,.vimrc,*.sh,*.c* :match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/
```

But when I open a file of another filetype, in the same session, this gives me the match `ColorColumn`.

Answer (score 4):

This might no longer be useful to the author, but I put the following in `.vim/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
if exists('+colorcolumn')
    setlocal colorcolumn=81
else
    au! BufEnter <buffer> match ColorColumn /\%81v.*/
endif
```

Since it's in ftplugin, it only occurs for python files, and BufEnter  keeps it local to the buffer that the python file is in.

Comment: This solution seems to hinge on exists()... without that part when I tried to apply it, it applied the match to all buffer types. I recommend @Rook's answer.

Comment: `match` applies to a window not a buffer, if you switch to a none python buffer in the same window, you will have the same highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
augroup longLines
    autocmd! BufEnter *.py,.vimrc,*.sh,*.c* :match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/                      
augroup END
```

Comment: I didn't actually understand your question to the detail, but that doesn't exactly do what you asked for.

Comment: my question is, if I open many files, how activate the match only in some files?

Comment: "many files" ?? Many files of a certain filetype or by extension or ... ? Filetype is activated by autocmd FileType, BufEnter by opening a buffer. Depends on what you want. Could you try to explain it a bit further?

Comment: many files, some *.py, some *.c, some *.txt

Comment: See my answer. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

This will make the highlighting active when [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) or [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) filetypes are open (feel free to add the others in there. I didn't know what filetype *.sh extension belongs to), and make it go away for all the others.

```
augroup LongLines
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType * match none
    autocmd FileType python,c,sh match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/
augroup END
```

Comment: *.sh is a bash file, a `sh` filetype

Comment: @juanpablo - Updated the answer to include sh.

Comment: what if I want to apply highlight to an already active buffer, i.e. not by .vimrc loading but by explicit on-the-fly command `call matchadd()` and still want to guarantee it affects the file's buffer only if its extension is specific? Is there a `autocmd` associated (like "apply immediately") or some kind of an `if` guard must be used?

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here ignore that match is WINDOW LOCAL ONLY! Highly commented code below to explain how to add match for a certain filetypes only.

The question asked is "In Vim how I can set a local match only for a specific filetype?" Below answers that, but for the case of trailing whitespace instead of colour column.

```
" Create a highlight group with the colours we wish to apply
hi _MatchTrailingWhitespace guibg=#880000 " Highlight trailing whitespace

function! AddWindowMatches()
    " match is WINDOW LOCAL ONLY, so we have to jump through some hoops to
    " make it apply to buffers only. i.e. we cant just use :setlocal match!

    " First clear all matches on the window, then we will add back the matches
    " required for each file type
    call clearmatches()

    " TRAILING WHITESPACE
    " Must escape the plus, match one or more space before the end of line
    " match trailing whitespace, except when typing at the end of a line.
    " If the filetype is python or javascript
    if index(['python', 'javascript'], &ft) >= 0
        " Can use the :match command, or the matchadd() function which returns a handle 
        " to the match, so it can easily be cleared with matchdelete(), not used here
        "match _MatchTrailingWhitespace /\s\+$/
        let w:match_trailing_space_id = matchadd('_MatchTrailingWhitespace', '\s\+$', -1)        
    endif
endfunction

augroup add_window_matches
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinEnter * :call myal#AddWindowMatches()
augroup END
```

Refer to `:help :match` and `:help matchadd()`